In a sequence if a successor $s_{n+1} \lt \frac{1}{2}\cdot s_n$ holds for each n, then $s_{n+1} \lt \frac{1}{2^{n}}\cdot s_1$ why is this true?
Problem 1.29 in Lax's Calculus book where $s_1$ = 2 and sequence elements $s_n$ are closer approximations to $\sqrt{2}$.
If this inequality holds for all n in the sequence:

$0 \lt s_{n+1} - \sqrt{2} \lt \frac{1}{2}(s_n - \sqrt{2})$

Then:

$0 \lt s_{n+1} - \sqrt{2} \lt \frac{1}{2^{n}}(s_1 - \sqrt{2})$

Writing out examples $\frac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{2^n}$ looks like a larger bound than the precision of the nth element but I suspect there is some simple algebra deduction here I missed.

Very easy. Use induction.

@geetha290krm If it was easy for them, they wouldn't have asked in the first place. just saying "very easy" (subjective) "use induction" (obvious) is not helpful

@Michael I added 'very easy' only because there is a minimum nunber of characters for a comment. Sorry if I hurt OP.

Observe that $$0 < s_{n+1} - \sqrt{2} < \frac{1}{2}(s_n - \sqrt{2})   \ \ \ \ (*)$$ by what we are told. However, the right hand side is precisely $$\frac{s_n - \sqrt{2}}{2} $$
We were told that the rule $(*)$ holds for all $n$. Therefore, it will apply to the numerator of the above fraction:
$$\frac{s_n - \sqrt{2}}{2} < \frac{\frac{1}{2}(s_{n-1} - \sqrt{2})}{2} = \frac{s_{n-1} - \sqrt{2}}{2^2}$$
Now you just keep going, applying the same rule we were given to the numerator $n$ times until you reach $s_1$ (notice the powers of $2$ in the denominator are increasing by $1$ every time).
